# How to get Microsoft Security Essentials to work through a proxy?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, proxy, ms-security-essentials

It only seems to work for me with a direct connect.

And i cant find anywhere to set a proxy.

Windows 7 64bit.

As for why... we are in development network that is isolated from the organizations production network. So we just wanted a lightweight virus scanner without having to setup any corporate update server or the like.

Comment: http://all-things-pure.blogspot.com/2009/10/microsoft-security-essentials-network.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case max's blogspot link breaks...

To get IE proxy settings to apply to other user accounts (which applications may use specifically), enter the following in a command prompt:

```
proxycfg -u
```

The -u option copies the proxy settings from the currently logged in user.

In Windows Vista and 7, `proxycfg` has been deprecated, so use the following instead:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy ie
```

Comment: Even after using that, and having checked that the proxy works in IE and can browse web sites, it still fails to update. I see it is trying to connect to some Akamai IP address and not to the proxy server one